# How do I grab several elements and wrap them in a div using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am familiar with `wrap()` and `innerWrap()`, which grabs every div and individually wraps each instance of the div in a `wrap()` parameters. IE:

```
<div class="wrap me"></div>
<div class="wrap me"></div>
<div class="wrap me"></div>
```

Becomes

```
<div class="wrapped"><div class="wrap me"></div></div>
<div class="wrapped"><div class="wrap me"></div></div>
<div class="wrapped"><div class="wrap me"></div></div>
```

I want it to be

```
<div class="wrapped">    
    <div class="wrap me"></div>
    <div class="wrap me"></div>
    <div class="wrap me"></div>
</div>
```

How do I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a [`.wrapAll()`](http://api.jquery.com/wrapAll/) for this:

```
$(".wrap.me").wrapAll("<div class='wrapped'></div>");
```

[You can give it a try here](http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/RjJhY/).

Answer (score 1):

Use [`.wrapAll()`](http://api.jquery.com/wrapall/).

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/twHmM/

```
$('.wrap.me').wrapAll('<div class="wrapped" />');
```